# Gap between xaxis and bars in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am adding a bar chart with tikzpicture and I am getting a strange gap between the bars and the y axis. Am I doing something obviously wrong? Because my other bar charts works fine... Should I specify the yaxis domain or something?

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 ybar=8pt,%=8pt, % configures ‘bar shift’
     enlargelimits=0.25,
    ylabel={Number of Instances},
symbolic x coords={PRtest, PRtrain, POtest, POtrain},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
]
\addplot coordinates {(PRtest, 10) (PRtrain, 117)(POtest, 35) (POtrain, 218)};
\addplot coordinates {(PRtest, 30)(PRtrain, 243)(POtest, 5) (POtrain, 142)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: you are enlarging the limits. You can enforce the enlargement to be done only in the upper part. See the manual for `enlargelimits`

Comment: The gap becomes a bit smaller then, but still present.

Comment: ok, removing the limits, AND adding     xmin=0,
    ymin=0, solves it! Thanks!

Comment: Try `enlarge x limits=0.25,
     ymin=0,` instead of `enlargelimits=0.25`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the limits, AND adding xmin=0, ymin=0, solves it! Thanks!